# Google Test - Using "SetUpTestSuite" doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, unit-testing, automated-tests, googletest, test-suite

I'm trying to write a test suite that performs a test-suite level "Set Up" operation.

I attempted to write a simple program first to try and get it working but I am not having any luck getting the "SetUpTestSuite" method to be called.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyTest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    static void SetUpTestSuite() {
        std::cerr << "TestSuiteSetup" << std::endl;
    }

    static void TearDownTestSuite() {

    }
};

TEST_F(MyTest, Case1) {
    std::cerr << "TESTING" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
[==========] Running 1 tests from 1 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.

[----------] 1 test from MyTest
[ RUN      ] MyTest.Case1
TESTING
[       OK ] MyTest.Case1 (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 tests from 1 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 tests.
```

For some reason `SetUpTestSuite()` is never called.

---

I have been reading through the [Sharing Resources Between Tests in the Same Suite](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite) section of the Google Test documentation but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Is there something I am missing?

---

*Note: I am using gtest v1.6.0 - it is the only package that was available from my companies Red Hat RPM repository.*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The documentation appears to be wrong. These methods should be called `SetUpTestCase()` and `TearDownTestCase()`. At least in Google Test 1.8.0.

Comment: The names [were recently changed](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/3a460a26b7a91abf87af7f31b93d29f930e25c82) to `SetUpTestSuite()` and `TearDownTestSuite()` as per the documentation.

Comment: Just how do you you swim in _that_?

Answer (score 4):

The change does not appear to have been released. The documents appear to be current with the Master branch, not the released version.

Answer (score 0):

If your code-under-test throws exceptions, the gtest framework will catch them and still shutdown using `TestDownTestSuite()`. BUT if you launch some threads in your test case and *they* throw, then there is nothing to catch them and your process will likely call `terminate()` and the process will immediately halt and there will be no tear down.  Be sure to catch exceptions in worker threads, or use `std::async` to create `std::future`s, which will automatically catch exceptions and rethrow them in the context of the original thread (when you call `future.get()`) which will be caught by gtest.

This happened to me I started using the unsupported `TEST_TIMEOUT_BEGIN()` and `TEST_TIMEOUT_FAIL_END()` macro hacks (http://antonlipov.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-timeout-tests-in-gtest.html) and then exceptions started happening.